# How to call a variable with a variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Inside of a function I'm getting a value from an input box, like this.

```
    var $value = $('#inputid').val().toLowerCase();
```

So I want to have the returned variable `$value` be used to call another variable.
Above that code is a variable declaration.

```
    var $somethingA = "1";
    var $somethingB = "2";
```

If the user types in "somethingA" I want to get an alert that says "1". Is this possible?

Sorry if it is a silly question. 
Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript dynamic variable name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/javascript-dynamic-variable-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's possible, but you need to use an object as a map rather than multiple variables to hold your values.

```
var inputMap = {
    somethingA: 1,
    somethingB: 2
};

var input = $('#inputid').val().toLowerCase();

alert(inputMap[input]);
```

*Note that if you were in the global scope (which would be a bad practice) you could just get the same effect by accesing variables using `window[someDynamicProperty]`, since global variables are properties of the `window` object in a browser environment.*

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I wanted, Thanks!